# How to make an Android app that is overlayed over the home screen

Tags: c++, android-ndk, facebook-messenger, homescreen

I intend to create an **app that will be overlayed on top of the normal "home" Android screen**.

I have only seen this done before with the **Facebook Messenger app**: it puts a floating, draggable icon in the **homescreen** whenever I get a message, and if touched it opens on top of everything else.

I would like to make an app that can show animated graphics similarly floating around on top of the **homescreen**, with user interaction possible.

My most preferred way would be with **Adobe AIR**. :-) But that might be too much to ask. :-)

My second best preferred way to do it would be through **Visual Studio 2015 C++**, i.e. the Android NDK. Is it possible? Or is the standard Java SDK the only way to go?

***Bonus PS.*** I haven't said anything about **iOS** cause I assume it is not possible at all on that platform. Or is it?

Comment: Huge discussion about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top).

Comment: @Steeve Thanks, but is it possible *without Java*?